# Checking html hidden value in jstl <c:if>

Tags: java, jquery, html, jstl

I have one html input hidden

```
<input type="hidden" id="todayRunJnID" name="todayRunJnID" value="some value"/>
```

and also have a table using jstl `<c:forEach>` in the same jsp page

```
<c:forEach items="${todaysRunJnList}" var="todayRunJn">                     
    <tr>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${todayRunJn.uploadedBy}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${todayRunJn.startDateTime}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${todayRunJn.status}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I would like to check the input hidden value includes in `<c:forEach>` items like this.

```
<c:forEach items="${todaysRunJnList}" var="todayRunJn"> 
    <c:if test="${todayRunJn.id == input hidden value}">
        <tr>
           ...
        </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Is it possible? According to the requirement, I don't want to call servlet again. The input hidden value come from jquery function.So this value is dynamic.

```
$(".runJnId").click(function() {
    var valueId = $(this).data('id');
    $("#todayRunJnID").val(valueId);
});
```

Comment: Is your HTML hidden value a variable that's set? i.e. `<input type="hidden" id="todayRunJnID" name="todayRunJnID" value="${something}"/>`

Comment: No it is come from jquery

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye Call me if I'm wrong, as far as I know JSTL has no connection to the rendered Browser output.

Comment: What is the type of `todaysRunJnList` items? Could you share the code?

Comment: @reporter Yes I think so. But I looking for some opinions from SO.